# OAuth exception with invalid application id

Tags: android, facebook

Actually we created an app inside facebook and using the app id provided, the android application was able to post messages.
Recently we changed the facebook username and primary email address.
After this, our app stopped working on the facebook login. It doesnt event show us the facebook login screen in the webview.

We are getting the following exception
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Error validating application. Invalid application ID.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 101
   }
}

Will be happy is someone helps us out in this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you delete the app accidentally?

Comment: If we have not deleted the app, then the app would remain under this same account where we have just renamed the username? Might be that problem. But can we create a new appid for for posting messages from the app which I have already launched in market and upgrade the existing market app with a new app which has the new app id for posting messages to facebook? Any help is appreciated. Thanks lgy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app's code references an app ID, which is needed for the app to work with Facebook's API - If you cannot access that app ID via the API (a GET request to `graph.facebook.com/<app ID here>` will return an 'Unsupported GET request' error for an inaccessible app) it means that it's either in sandbox mode, and you can fix this from the app settings, or it's been deleted.

If the latter you'll need to create a new app and update your Android code to use that new App's app ID instead

Comment: Thanks for the update. When I tried the appid with the above graph url, I am getting the following. <br> {
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: <APPID>",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803
   }
} <br> Can we create a new app id in facebook developer website and use that app id for the existing app itself? Is this possible?

Comment: I've edited my answer to be clearer; **If the latter you'll need to create a new app and update your Android code to use that new App's app ID instead**

Comment: Thanks lgy. Will have to do it.